# yii2, kartik\slider\Slider, не отображает tooltip на bootstrap 4

Tags: php, yii2, kartik

Я использую виджет kartik\slider\Slider
https://demos.krajee.com/slider

мои настройки в common/config/params.php

```
<?php
return [
    'bsVersion' => '4.x',
    'bsDependencyEnabled' => false,
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
    'supportEmail' => 'support@example.com',
    'senderEmail' => 'noreply@example.com',
    'senderName' => 'Example.com mailer',
    'user.passwordResetTokenExpire' => 3600,
    'user.passwordMinLength' => 8,
];
```

код вывода виджета

```
 <?php
                    echo '<b class="badge">від 15000</b> ' . Slider::widget([
                            'name' => 'price-filter search-price-filter',
                            'value' => '15000,50000',
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'tooltip'=>'always', //отображать сверху tooltip
                                'min' => 15000,
                                'max' => 50000,
                                'range' => true,
                            ],
                        ]) . ' <b class="badge">до 50000</b>';
                    ?>
```

у меня отображает ползунок. Но при передвижении ползунка не отображает `tooltip`(делаю как описано в документации).

Описание в документации (https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/blob/master/README.md#options)

Проблема заключается в том что это не работает на bootstrap4, но работает на версии bootstrap3. Как сделать чтобы работало на bootstrap4 ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На сайте картика я тоже не вижу никаких тултипов на его демках)) Может что-то сломалось)

Comment: Мда, я думал что у меня что то не так. Очень странно что не работает. Спасибо

Comment: Я понял проблему. У меня bootstrap 4, и именно на нем оно не работает. Нa Bootstrap3 - работает(поменяю вопрос)

Comment: Различие между `bs4` и `bs3` для `tooltip` в методе инициализации. Для `bs3` это `$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();`, а для `bs4` это по-моему `$("[data-toggle='bs-popover']").popover();`. Ну и для `bs4` нужна отдельная библиотека `popper.js`

Answer (score 1):

Тултипы не отображаются, потому что они прозрачные.

```css
.tooltip.top {
  opacity: 1;
}
```